# Prevent memory leaks and easy/idiomatic programming in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

Is there a compromise between managing memory and easy/idiomatic programming in C++?

For example, let's say I have the following classes. We have an `Item` that someone may purchase, and a `ShoppingList` of those `Items`. Let's just say `Item` and `ShoppingList` are big data structures with more features than shown and that we would not want to pass them by value normally (but they are stripped down to the basics features in this example).

```
class Item {
 private:
  std::string name;
  float cost;
 public:
  Item(std::string name, float cost) : name{name}, cost{cost} { }
  std::string toString(void) {
    return name + " = " + std::to_string(cost);
  }
  ~Item() { std::cout << "~Item()" << std::endl; }
};

class ShoppingList {
 private:
  std::vector<Item *> items;
 public:
  ShoppingList() {}
  void addItem(Item &item) {
    items.push_back(&item);
  }
  std::vector<Item *> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
  ~ShoppingList() {
    std::cout << "~ShoppingList()" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Now, I want to be able to `conveniently` do something like the following (inline the argument).

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};
shoppingList.add(Item{"soap", 1.99}); // no
```

C++17 will not me allow to try this either.

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};
shoppingList.add(&Item{"soap", 1.99}); // no
shoppingList.add(new Item{"soap", 1.99}); // no
```

Instead, I have to do something like this.

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};

Item soap{"soap", 1.99};
shoppingList.add(soap);
```

The above is "ok" for adding 1 element, but things get "worse" when I try to use a for loop. The `item` created on each loop ends with the same address and I do not end up with the intended effect.

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};

auto products = std::vector<std::string>{"brush", "comb"};
for (auto product : products) {
  Item item{product, 0.99};
  shoppingList.addItem(item);
}
```

It seems unreasonable, to me, to do the following.

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};

Item item1{"item1", 0.99};
Item item2{"item2", 0.99};
Item item3{"item3", 0.99};
// and so on

shoppingList.addItem(item1);
shoppingList.addItem(item2);
shoppingList.addItem(item3);
// and so on
```

There's just so many ways of thinking about how to make it easier to use the code. One way would be to use raw pointers. So I may change the method signature of `ShoppingList.addItem(...)` to as follows.

```
void addItem(Item *item);
```

Then I can do some less difficult use of the objects as follows.

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};
shoppingList.addItem(new Item{"item1", 0.99});
shoppingList.addItem(new Item{"item2", 0.99});
shoppingList.addItem(new Item{"item3", 0.99});
```

With this new method signature, for loops should work.

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};

auto products = std::vector<std::string>{"brush", "comb"};
for (auto product : products) {
  shoppingList.addItem(new Item{product, 0.99});
}
```

Ok, so this approach makes it easier to use/write the code, but `valgrind` analysis says `Leak_DefintelyLost` where I start using `new`.

Another approach is smart pointers. So let's wrap the objects into smart pointers; in particular `shared_pointer`. Here's the new `ShoppingList` using smart pointers.

```
class ShoppingList {
 private:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> items;
 public:
  ShoppingList() {}
  void addItem(std::shared_ptr<Item> item) {
    items.push_back(item);
  }
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> getItems() {
    return items;
  }
  ~ShoppingList() {
    std::cout << "~ShoppingList()" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Usage will look like the following.

```
ShoppingList shoppingList{};
shoppingList.addItem(std::make_shared<Item>("soap", 32.0));
shoppingList.addItem(std::make_shared<Item>("shampoo", 32.0));
```

`valgrind` does not detect a single memory leak issue.

The only problem I have with using `shared_ptr` is verbosity and nested types. This declaration looks bad to me. That is a lot of `:` and `<` with `>`.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item>> items;
```

In one situation where I had a map of maps of big data structures, I considered using shared pointers and ended up with a declaration as follows. If another coder looks at what the intention is (or if I myself come back later to troubleshoot), what is the intention here?

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>>> dataBag;
```

It seems to me that the `:` and `<` and `>` are polluting the code and intent all for the purpose of managing memory leaks. I am not sure what's good or bad or idiomatic to write C++17 while being concise but also preventing memory leaks boostrapped by the language constructs.

Now, I did encounter the idea of [RAII](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/RAII). But mocking some classes with that approach (raw pointers only), `valgrind` still shows `Leak_DefinitelyLost`.

Any general guidance on I suppose what I would refer to as idiomatic C++ that is memory leakage sensitive/preventative would be helpful. I was going to go down the road of creating factories to store all the pointers that I will create across my API, but I realized that approach would cause the memory to continue to build up even when there are no longer references to some pointers (and smart pointers already handle that part).

At this point, I am almost resigned to the acceptance of living with smart pointers (though there may be diamond and colon operators all over the place) to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Why are you even using pointers?  `std::vector<Item>` will do you just fine.  You really only need a pointer type when you need polymorphism.  If you're not doing that, you should stick with value types.

Comment: Why does your `ShoppingList` contains a vector of *pointers* instead of a vector of *object instances*? This is a good way to crash your code, storing pointers to objects that don't exist anymore.

Comment: First rule of C++: do not use plain pointers unless you really have a reason to do so. And you almost never have a valid reason to use a vector of pointers.

Comment: Good questions on pointers vs instances. The example above is just a `mock` example to illustrate some of my cognitive distress. I thought, in general, if a data structure is big (or complicated), don't pass them by value but by reference instead. Isn't a std::vector<Pointer *> more memory friendly than std::vector<Pointer>?

Comment: That looks like a good time to use an alias. `using bagmap = td::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>>>>` and then `bagmap databag;` Sometimes you have to alias for readability, but agree with the above. Why pointers in the first place?

Comment: *Isn't a std::vector<Pointer *> more memory friendly than std::vector<Pointer>* depends on what you're going to do with it. If there are a lot of inserts and removes relative to iterations, the pointer might be the better choice. If you mostly iterate, all those pointers can slow you way way way down. The structure is no longer as cache friendly.

Comment: Maybe I am trying to over-optimize with `std::vector<Clazz *>` vs `std::vector<Clazz>`. My understanding is pass-by-reference is faster (only address is passed) than pass-by-value (stuff gets copied to the stack). That is one of the motivating reason.

Comment: Profile and find out. The modern compiler is an absolute whiz at eliminating unnecessary copies. [Here's a piece by the God-Emperor of C++](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists) on a thought exercise. It intersects nicely with what you're working through.

Comment: Unless `Item` is a polymorphic base for other classes - which it isn't in the code you have shown -  there is no need to manage a collection of pointers in `std::vector<Item *>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> >`.   Instead, simply manage a `std::vector<Item>`.    If `Item` is a polymorphic base, then better to manage a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Item> >` than a vector of raw pointers.   If your experimentation with RAII didn't work out, you didn't do it right - which means your "mocking with raw pointers" didn't cover all the needed bases.

Comment: @Peter I agree. RAII is not easy to get right. I like user4581301 advice though; the "pollution" could all be aliased and the common advice on sticking with smart pointers might just be the long-term win.

Comment: @JaneWayne - RAII isn't that difficult.   The core principle is every constructor sets up invariants (set of conditions that are always true for the class, including how it tracks resources), all accessible functions maintain those invariants (e.g. if the class maintains a collection, all member functions ensure the collection is valid), and the destructor can rely on the invariants, and therefore clean up safely.   This means ensuring there is no way for other functions to screw up the internal state of an object.

Answer (score 1):

One way or another, if you want a collection of items, you're going to have to create each item in the collection. Storing pointers to items mostly helps if they're really so tremendously huge that copying them is unacceptable, even if it happens only a few times, such as when a vector reallocates its memory.

As for passing by reference: right now, you're defining the parameter as an lvalue reference. That means the reference can only refer to an lvalue. Thus the requirement to create a named object (an lvalue) then pass it.

You apparently don't want that. In your case, you have a couple of choices. One is a reference to const. Unlike a (non-const) lvalue reference, this can bind to a temporary object.

Another choice would be to use an rvalue reference. An rvalue reference has the advantage that it can bind to an rvalue (such as a temporary object), and also that it's "aware" that it's dealing with an rvalue, so it can "steal" the contents of that object. This is particularly useful if the object mostly contains a pointer to the actual data, in which case you can just copy the pointer (and modify the existing object so it won't destroy the data when it's destroyed).

In most cases, you're best off starting with the simplest code that could work. Create the vector of objects, and live with the fact that they'll get copied. Sometime later, if you find that you have a real bottleneck from copying those objects as that vector is reallocated, it's soon enough to change your code--such as to store `std::unique_ptr`s instead of storing objects directly. But that's not your first choice. Chances are pretty good that when you profile the code, you'll find that copying those objects isn't a bottleneck at all, so putting work into keeping them from being copied would have been wasted.

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I get `c++` advice.

> Never use raw pointers.

As soon as you are not low-level library developer. You don't need raw pointers. Don't need. Period.